# IF Dropdown Value = X

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Super simple question.. I've got a dropdown select menu:

```
    <select id="builder">
        <option value="none">---</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
```

I'm trying to get a simple Javascript script to run, something like this:

> if document.getElementById("builder").value = "one" { 
>   alert("ONE!") }

what syntax should I use to check which value is selected in a dropdown menu?

Comment: So what's the question? Also, know the difference between `=`, `==` and `===`

Comment: what syntax should I use to check which value is selected in a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change):

```
document.getElementById('builder').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.value === 'one') {
    alert('one');
  }
});
```